# Disabling trigger using sp_msforeachtable is very slow

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, triggers

As part of a larger bulk data insert into our system, I have a stored procedure that disables all table triggers at the start of the process and enables them once the data insert has completed

When running this on our development environment, this used to take a few seconds but now keeps going for quite a few minutes before I cancel the operation

```
exec sp_msforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? DISABLE TRIGGER all'
```

I would like to understand what factors could be affecting the performance of this command

No other users are writing/reading to the database and there has been no change in the number of tables.

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks, was exactly that

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Having the same problem but I don't understand what you mean by "check for blocking". Can you both answer & accept the question, please? That's kinda the point of asking questions here...